# NullPointerException at android.widget.AdapterView.getPositionForView(AdapterView.java:581)

Tags: android, android-listview

I know this has been discussed before, and I searched through a lot of results, and none of them solved my problem.

I get:
NullPointerException
at android.widget.AdapterView.getPositionForView(AdapterView.java:581)

I have a ListView with checkboxes. the behavior I want is that after an item is checked, it's moved to the bottom of the list, in a way that the list first displays the non checked items and then the checked ones.

Here's the relevant part from the Adapter implementation getView:

```
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        layoutProductItem = new LinearLayout(ctx);
        mInflater.inflate(R.layout.product_in_list, layoutProductItem, true);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.chk = (CheckBox) layoutProductItem.findViewById(R.id.chk_in_cart);
        layoutProductItem.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        layoutProductItem = (LinearLayout) convertView;
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    TextView viewProdName = (TextView) layoutProductItem.findViewById(R.id.txt_prod_name);
    TextView viewRequiredQttyName = (TextView) layoutProductItem.findViewById(R.id.txt_required_qtty);
    EditText fldQtty = (EditText) layoutProductItem.findViewById(R.id.fld_qtty);
    EditText fldPrice = (EditText) layoutProductItem.findViewById(R.id.fld_price);
    holder.chk.setOnCheckedChangeListener(checkedChangeListener);
    viewProdName.setText(prod.getProduct().getName());
    fldQtty.setText("" + prod.getBoughtQuantity());
    fldPrice.setText("" + prod.getPricePerSingleItem());
    viewRequiredQttyName.setText("" + prod.getRequiredQuantity());
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            holder.chk.setChecked(prod.isInCart());
        }
    };
    layoutProductItem.post(runnable);
```

without the line holder.chk.setChecked(prod.isInCart()); there is no exception, but all the checkboxes are marked when the user checks one of them.

The problem I assume is with the reordering of the list according to the checked status.
Without it, there are no issues.

I considered giving the checkboxes up, and go with context menu operations, but I think that the reordering will cause this again.
This is also the case if I want to use ExpandableListView. Once the reordering will occur, the getPositionForView method will not find the object in the previous position (my assumption, not knowledge).

Thanks

Comment: Please show code for reordering. You may need to have a separate copy of your array that you do the reordering in, and then swap the array into the adapter after you've updated it.

Comment: reordering code:

public void reorder() {
        Collections.sort(listCurrentProducts);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

Comment: @omerkeynan Did you get any solution ? I am facing the same problem when dragging an item and dropping at bottom of the window or as last list item.

Comment: @karthikeyan-ve
I haven't touched this project for so long, that I can't remember if I solved the problem.
Sorry.